# Django: how to create manytomany field across app

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I was trying to extend the auth.models Group for some extra fields. Here is what I have done in myapp.models.py:

```
class ProfileGroupBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        module = attrs.pop('__module__')
        parents = [b for b in bases if isinstance(b, ProfileGroupBase)]
        if parents:
            fields = []
            for obj_name, obj in attrs.items():
                if isinstance(obj, models.Field): fields.append(obj_name)
                Group.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
        return super(ProfileGroupBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class ProfileGroup(object):
    __metaclass__ = ProfileGroupBase

class MyGroup(ProfileGroup):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
```

With these code, mobile and email fields will be added to the Group on the admin page. Now I want to add another manytomany field, so I added this under class MyGroup(ProfileGroup):

```
  annotations = models.ManyToManyField(Annotation, verbose_name=_('annotation'), blank=True)
```

Then I created a new model Annotation under the same models.py file:

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

However, there comes an error: name 'Annotation' is not defined. I am wondering even the class MyGroup and class Annotation are defined under the same models.py, they are actually separated. I am so confused, does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, you defined the `Annotation` model after the previous model where you have a many to many relation.

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Just cut the code for the `Annotation` model and paste it before the other model.

Comment: Oops, I forgot this point...Thanks. But it reports another error: Local field 'annotations' in class 'MyGroup' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Group'.

Comment: `MyGroup(ProfileGroup):` inherits from `ProfileGroup`, please do post your `ProfileGroup` class.

Comment: ah wait, `__metaclass__ = ProfileGroupBase`, do paste the `ProfileGroupBase` base class.

Answer (score 1):

When defining ForeignKey or ManyToManyField you should define the other class using a string containing the application name and the model name instead of the actual class. So do this

```
annotations = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Annotation', 
 verbose_name=_('annotation'), blank=True)
```

This helps with references to not-yet-defined models but also with circular references. So I propose to always do it. Please also take a look at the foreignkey documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey